# Unable to filter data from database due to laravel blade curly braces "{{ }}"

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to filter data gotten from database  with the class="data-groups".

Here is the code:

```js
this.shuffle.filter(function(element, shuffle) {

    // If there is a current filter applied, ignore elements that don't match it.
    if (shuffle.group !== Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS) {
      // Get the item's groups.
      var groups = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-groups'));
      var isElementInCurrentGroup = groups.indexOf(shuffle.group) !== -1;

      // Only search elements in the current group
      if (!isElementInCurrentGroup) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    var titleElement = element.querySelector('.book-item_title');
    var titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();

    return titleText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
  });
};

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="grid-shuffle">
  <ul id="grid" class="row">
    @foreach($libraries as $library)

    <li class="book-item small-12 medium-6 columns" data-groups='["{{$library->genre}}"]' data-date-created='{{$library->published}}' data-title='{{ $library->title }}' data-color='{{$library->color}}'>
      <div class="bk-img">
        <div class="bk-wrapper">
          <div class="bk-book bk-bookdefault">
            <div class="bk-front">
              <div class="bk-cover" style="background-image: url('img/001-small.png')"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bk-back"></div>
            <div class="bk-left"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-details">
        <h3 class="book-item_title">{{$library->title}}</h3>
        <p class="author">{{$library->author}} &bull; {{$library->published}}</p>
        <p>{{$library->synopsis}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="button ">Details</a>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay-details">
        <a href="#" class="close-overlay-btn">Close</a>
        <div class="overlay-image">
          <img src="img/001.jpg" alt="Book Cover">
          <div class="back-color"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-desc activated">
          <h2 class="overlay_title">{{$library->title}}</h2>
          <p class="author">by {{$library->author}}</p>
          <p class="published">{{$library->published}}</p>
          <p class="synopsis">{{ $library->synopsis }}</p>
          <a href="#" class="button preview">Preview</a>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-preview">
          <a href="#" class="back-preview-btn">Back</a>
          <h4 class="preview-title">Preview</h4>
          <div class="preview-content">
            <h5>Chapter 1</h5>
            <p>{{$library->details}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is it doesn't work unless I hard code the genre like this

```
data-groups='["fiction"]'
```

Now since I'm retrieving data from a database using the foreach loop it means any book out the database is automatically given the "fiction" attribute regardless of its db assigned genre.

Any help on how to solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to show your `@foreach` loop to help us better understand your problem. Currently, I don't see what the issue is...

Comment: You're missing a $ for `genre`, it should be `$genre`.

Comment: @tim-lewis  Included the whole foreach loop.

Comment: @sam Mistake while typing.

Comment: Thanks. So why doesn't `{{ $library->genre }}` work here? Is the content of `$library->genre` incompatible/syntactically incorrect for where it's being used? Can you provide an example of what `$library->genre` contains compared to what you expect?

Comment: @tim-lewis **So why doesn't {{ $library->genre }} work here? **  Now that's what I can't figure out.  The $library->genre holds strings like fiction, adventure, etc.

Comment: @tim-lewis Sorry for wasting your time,  i found the problem,  i was filtering with `code <a href="#" class="filter-item" data-group="fantasy">Fantasy</a>
            <a href="#" class="filter-item" data-group="sci-fi">Sci-Fi</a>  code` while my db was giving out genre with typos in them. Is there a way to close this question ala github??

Comment: Haha, no worries; it happens. I can vote to close (don't have the rep/badges to close on my own), as there's an option for closing due to syntax/typo/etc errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the problem** 
I was Filtering with this lines of code

```html
<a href="#" class="filter-item active" data-group="all">All Categories</a>
<a href="#" class="filter-item" data-group="fantasy">Fantasy</a>
<a href="#" class="filter-item" data-group="sci-fi">Sci-Fi</a>
<a href="#" class="filter-item" data-group="classic">Classics</a>
<a href="#" class="filter-item" data-group="fairy">Fairy Tale</a>
```

The problem was that the data-group items are case sensitive. So for example I was filtering with "classic" while my database was providing "Classic" therefore making the filter function seem faulty.